# Domain name in URL is changing to EC2 Public DNS name

Tags: amazon-web-services, amazon-ec2, amazon-route53

I have Route53 configured lets say with `www.xyx.com` and my dummy ec2 instance public DNS is `ec2-54-111-11-11.us-west-2.compute.amazonaws.com`, when i enter `www.xyz.com` on the browser i can see that my address bar is changing from `www.xyz.com` to `ec2-54-111-11-11.us-west-2.compute.amazonaws.com` - what should i be doing so that my address bar always shows `www.xyz.com` and not the EC2 public DNS?

Thanks,
Deepak

Comment: what is you web server and how is it configured ? e.g. in Apache if you configure with `Listen 80` it will not change anything but if you specifically put the hostname or IP in your config it will change

Answer (score 0):

Can you please explain me how did you configured your Route 53 Hosted Zone with EC2 instance? What is your 'A' type record set in Route 53 pointed to? 
Create a Load Balancer and use that Load Balancer IP for your 'A' type record set.